# Is there a way to automatically include link querystrings when dynamically rendering Sitecore links?

Tags: links, link-manager

I have a number of places in my code where I render links from templates like so:

```
<a href="@(Model.Link == null ? string.Empty : Model.Link.Url)">@Model.Link.Text</a>
```

However I've realized that this leaves off any querystring that is set on the link. I know that I can add this manually by doing `href="@(Model.Link == null ? string.Empty : Model.Link.Url + "?" + Model.Link.Query)"` but is there a simpler way to just get the full link url and querystring, without having to explicitly include the query everywhere in my code?

Comment: The method you're looking for is `Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(Model, x => x.Link)`. Have a look at that and you should see the correct way to do this.

Comment: @Erica, did my answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved easily using Sitecore field helper methods like below :

Just change the anchor tag line from

```
<a href="@(Model.Link == null ? string.Empty : Model.Link.Url)">@Model.Link.Text</a>
```

to the format below

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field(string fieldName/fieldID, Item item)
```

This will help you to avoid the need to explicitly call the Link's query property everywhere in your code. Also, as far as I know, this is the best solution that reduces the need to write explicit code for adding other attributes such as href, text to the anchor tag. These basic link properties are automatically rendered in your code, if you just supply fieldName and an Item object.

ProTip:
If you need to add css classes or any additional attributes to the rendered link tag, just navigate to this helpful link written by Marcotana that I have been using for my reference and slightly tweak the code :
https://marcotanainsights.wordpress.com/2017/10/05/tips-on-using-html-sitecore-fields-parameters-object/